# Qual o significado e origem da expressão "ele é muito reinadinho"?

Tags: expressões, português-europeu, origem-histórica, significado-em-contexto

Em Lisboa ouvi a expressão "ele é muito reinadinho".

O que significa?
E qual a sua origem?

Comment: isso foi em qual contexto? No Brasil, usa-se "ele está reinando", quando alguém está reclamando de algo sem muita razão. Também se usa "reinando" para sinônimo de animal no período fertíl.

Comment: Percebi que era no contexto em que ele é falador , divertido , reinadinho . Ouvi em Lisboa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Reinar" significa, [segundo a Infopédia](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/reinar):

> 6. *coloquial* - folgar, divertir-se; brincar
> 7. *coloquial* - gracejar; fazer troça

Então eu entenderia "reinadinho" como o mesmo que "brincalhão", alguém que faz muitas brincadeiras, tira bastante sarro, ou até (se fosse no Brasil), que [faz travessuras](http://www.aulete.com.br/reinar).

Agora, o porquê de "reinar" também ter esse significado, não descobri e só posso especular que quem faz brincadeira ou troça tende a dominar (ou *reinar*) as atenções ou a situação.

Comment: És brasileiro, certo? Como a pergunta é sobre pt-PT, acho importante que esclareças explicitamente na tua resposta quanta... "autoridade" tens; parece-me que estás a deduzir (e muito bem, na minha opinião) com base no teu conhecimento e experiência em pt-BR, e acho que isso deve estar explícito na resposta.

Comment: @ANeves Acho que mesmo se fosse chinês a resposta não precisaria ser alterada. :-) Uso a Infopédia como fonte para a definição da palavra e, quando me refiro ao pt-BR, deixo explícito. A minha especulação no segundo parágrafo também está descrita como tal e se baseia numa observação social, muito mais do que de qualquer variedade do português ou de outra língua específica.

Comment: Tá, é justo. Dei uns retoques menores. O "porque" e "porquê" acho que fica mais claro para pt-PT assim; mas se não gostares, troca de volta, claro. :)

Comment: @ANeves Ficou ótimo, só mudei "InfoPédia" -> "Infopédia".